# Unable to broadcast an image on another image using python

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection

```
cropped_image_resized = cropped_image.resize((400, 100), 
Image.ANTIALIAS)
imshow(cropped_image_resized)

height = np.size(cropped_image, 0)
width = np.size(cropped_image, 1)
print(cropped_image.size)
print(height, width)

background_image = np.zeros([100,400,3],dtype=np.uint8)
imshow(background_image)

background_image[0:26,0:43] = cropped_image_resized
imshow(background_image)
```

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-061e7c389661> in <module>
----> 1 background_image[0:26,0:43] = cropped_image_resized
      2 imshow(background_image)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,400,3) into shape (26,43,3)```
````

Comment: Please show what tools you have imported.  What do you mean by broadcast? Do you mean display or view? If so, then the command depends upon what viewer you have imported. If Opencv, then it would be cv2.imshow(background_image)

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to take an image that is 400x100 and shoving it in a space of 26x43.

You either need to resize the cropped image to 26x43 (or smaller) or you need to change the dimensions of `background_image` that you’re trying to shove the cropped image into. For example:

```
cropped_image_resized = cropped_image.resize((26, 43), Image.ANTIALIAS)
background_image[0:26,0:43] = cropped_image_resized
```

Or this could work (I can’t check, but I believe it should?):

```
background_image = np.zeros([150,450,3],dtype=np.uint8)
background_image[:,:] = cropped_image_resized
```

Incidentally, the background image won’t be a background image anymore if you leave it as:

```
background_image = np.zeros([100,400,3],dtype=np.uint8)
```

As the original cropped image (400x100) will take up all available pixel values.

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-5da9dc1c4d77> in <module>
      1 background_image = np.zeros([150,450,3],dtype=np.uint8)
----> 2 background_image[:,:] = cropped_image

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (43,26,3) into shape (150,450,3)  

Even on trying it, it does show the same error

Comment: Try using `background_image[0:100, 0:400]` ?